# Is Mephisto susceptible to Holy Weapons in the Marvel Universe?

Tags: marvel, mephisto

Though only familiar with him through **Ghost Rider, Silver Surfer**, and that *atrocious* Spider-Man story (Sorry; I know we can all go one more day without speaking on that), as a kid, I envisioned Mephisto as a clearly more "diabolical brain" villain than one having any major raw power. *Then* I remember seeing his trading card; how was I to *know* the dude was an absolute **beast** ....

[image: Mephitso's trading card]

Note that a level 7 basically means no established limit (Hulk, for example, has a level 7 strength). As such, almost all of this characters stats are **off the charts!**

The *sole* exception to this is his Fighting Ability, which seems to be as pitiful as that of an untrained human... but then again, who needs to learn a martial art when you have basically unlimited strength, speed, stamina, durability, energy projection, mental power, can separate souls from their bodies, banish them to other dimensions and drop mountains on people with a thought!?

But any character must have some weaknesses... and he *is* a demon. So I wondered if Mephisto might have less power against or be hurt by holy/blessed items, such a rosaries, crosses, holy water, less Christian stuff like Buddha prayer beads, Jewish spells, Indian sutras and other Eastern religious iconography?

And what about more direct damage by actual *weapons* of goodness, like Excalibur, the spear o Light, Mjolnir and other such legendary weaponry? I've never seen him fight any of these personally, so this was supposition on my part.

**Do any canon or in-continuity examples of such happenings exist?**

Or perhaps is there a specific substance, item or class of items that can do *him* heavy damage in particular?

Comment: Thanos threatens to erase him from existence with the Infinity Gauntlet

Comment: @Valorum yeah, but I don't think an ultimate weapon that can rewrite the foundation of time, space and reality itself should count, as it could do that to BASICALLY EVERYBODY, including Cosmic entities, not just demons who may have a weakness to holy or blessed objects.

Comment: Indeed. And also not overtly holy, hence why it was posted as a comment

Comment: @Valorum Point taken. But considering it _can_ be seen as a weapon that makes a mortal as mighty as a God, while not explicitly "holy",, I think it can count as "divine", at least.

Comment: I think that bubblegum card ranking of his fighting style is because I can't recall Mephisto ever actually putting up his dukes.  He relies on vassals and traps and tricks to do the physical stuff.  I strongly suspect mere symbols and jewelry have no effect–it's the quality of belief from whoever holding the symbols that might have potency.  The only sort of reference I can cite is "Thor" #180 (1970).  The spirit of Thor is trapped in Loki's body.  Mephisto touches "Loki" in a spirit of camaraderie and the noble, good, brave spirit of Thor causes Mephisto a sharp jolt of pain.